# Problem with visualization with Python Plotly Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, seaborn

I have Pandas data frame like this: `data = pd.DataFrame({"Risk":["good", "bad", "good", "good", "bad"], "Age":[22, 50, 43, 27, 19]})`

and I wan to achieve something like this:
[image]

Why my code does not work ? Could you repare my code? I have error that: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.tools as tls
import chart_studio.plotly as py
df_good = data.loc[data["Risk"] == 'good']['Age'].values.tolist()
df_bad = data.loc[data["Risk"] == 'bad']['Age'].values.tolist()
df_age = data['Age'].values.tolist()


#First plot
trace0 = go.Histogram(
    x=df_good,
    histnorm='probability',
    name="Good Credit"
)
#Second plot
trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=df_bad,
    histnorm='probability',
    name="Bad Credit"
)
#Third plot
trace2 = go.Histogram(
    x=df_age,
    histnorm='probability',
    name="Overall Age"
)

#Creating the grid
fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, specs=[[{}, {}], [{'colspan': 2}, None]],
                          subplot_titles=('Good','Bad', 'General Distribuition'))

#setting the figs
fig.append_trace(trace0, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)

fig['layout'].update(showlegend=True, title='Age Distribuition', bargap=0.05)
py.iplot(fig, filename='custom-sized-subplot-with-subplot-titles')
```

Comment: You must have over written `data` with a list somewhere?

Comment: Is this your whole code?

Comment: Please may you update your question with more of your code wrt `data`. As sdhaus says, it seems like it has been overwritten by a list at some point.